# What is this minifig/minidoll?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I found this minifig or minidoll.

What is it and where is it from?

I tried asking the people in the store, but they didn't know, and I couldn't find much by searching since I don't even know what type of minifig it is.

[image: front]
[image: back]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [Jack Stone](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=44031#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), a figure AFOLs love to hate.

from [4617-1: Dual Turbo Prop](https://brickset.com/sets/4617-1/Dual-Turbo-Prop)

[image]

Comment: Brickipedia page

https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_Stone_(Theme)